# Gnome system control window not grab focus

Tags: gnome, window, focus

The version of my Ubuntu is 22.04 and the GNOME is gnome-42-2204.

I press 'Ctrl+Alt+Tab' to switch system controls, then I choose 'DASH' or 'Top Bar', and they are highlighted
[desktop dock screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZPjf.png)

But when I try to press 'Left' of 'Right' key to move between icons, there is no any reaction. It seems like that the 'DASH' or 'Top Bar' dosen't grab the focus.But there is not any windows on my desktop.

Who can help me, thanks!